# Where can I find Symfony2 unit tests?

Tags: symfony

Their google group is slow, the phpBB-forum is weak and spammed, the documentation is sparse ... so please tell me somebody where to finde unit test of symfony2 components!

Neither in the distribution nor on GitHub I made a find.

Comment: If you want fast help, use the IRC channel. That's where most of the devs hang out and so do the people with depper knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in Github, in the **tests** folder.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/tests

Comment: upps ... right, my fault. I was looking in the components repos ... as I think that's where they belong if sf2 wants to achieve loosely coupledness.

Comment: The bundle-specific tests can be found in `src/Symfony/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests`.